# strtok() while loop is returning extra blank/place holder and not specified string

Tags: c, string, treeview, delimiter, strtok

I have a path to some folders as a string and using strtok() to break down subfolders separated by , delimiter. Issue is when its printing in a TreeControl view (runs successfully) but its printing an extra blank folder (dotted/line space) for what looks like a future folder maybe? how do I get rid of that blank folder and only show the 2 folders (Pop, Country).
I tried adding picture but not working so here is what it looks like on the treeview:

```
->/Desktop/Songs
  ->.....      this is where the blank is being inserted
  ->Pop
  ->Country
```

Code:

```
HTREEITEM hItem;
HTREEITEM hsubItem;

char line[] = "/Desktop/Songs,Pop,Country" ;   
char* dir= strtok(line,",");    
printf("%s\n", dir);
hItem= treeview.InsertItem(dir); //add to a tree control as the root path or directory

while (dir!= NULL)
{
  dir= strtok(NULL,",");
  printf("%s\n", dir);
  hsubItem = treeview.InsertItem(dir, hItem); //add Pop Country below the first item 
}
```

Comment: Explain that loop to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), particularly in consideration of what `strtok` returns when it *fails*, and what you do between the time that fail happens and the next check of the while-condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `dir = strtok(NULL,",");` is `NULL` the code is doing the same thing as when `dir` is not `NULL`.

Fix it by checking `dir` is not `NULL` after the call to `strtok` inside the loop, and only treat `dir` as valid if it is not `NULL`. For example:

```
while (dir!= NULL)
{
  dir= strtok(NULL,",");
  if (dir != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", dir);
    hsubItem = treeview.InsertItem(dir, hItem); //add Pop Country below the first item 
  }
}
```

The above code can be optimized to only test `dir` once per iteration:

```
if (dir!= NULL)
{
  while (1)
  {
    dir= strtok(NULL,",");
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
      break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", dir);
    hsubItem = treeview.InsertItem(dir, hItem); //add Pop Country below the first item 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` is not as difficult to use as all that.

```
int main( void ) {
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    char *sepChars = " ";

    int i = 0;
    for( char *pTok = str; ( pTok = strtok( pTok, sepChars ) ) != NULL; pTok = NULL )
        printf( "Token #%d: '%s'\n", i++, pTok );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Token #0: 'The'
Token #1: 'quick'
Token #2: 'brown'
Token #3: 'fox'
Token #4: 'jumps'
Token #5: 'over'
Token #6: 'the'
Token #7: 'lazy'
Token #8: 'dog'
```